# How to display two fields in gxt ComboBox?

Tags: java, gwt, combobox, gxt

I have an object with two essential fields that must be displayed for the user together in ComboBox something kind of:

```
 MyObject { 
            Long id;
            Integer from;
            Integer to;
            ...
          }
```

My properties look like :

```
 MyObjectProperties { 
            ModelKeyProvider<MyObject> id();
            LabelProvider<MyObject> from();
            LabelProvider<MyObject> to();
            ...
          }
```

I'm trying to display `**from - to**` in each combobox cell, is it possible using GXT 3 ComboBox?

That's not working for me because i can't use [LabelProvider](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/LabelProvider.html) for an int and can't merge two wroperties in same field!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LabelProvider is in fact the only clean way to go, but you need only one LabelProvider:

```
LabelProvider<MyObject> labelProvider = new LabelProvider<MyObject>(){
    @Override
    public String getLabel(MyObject item){
        return item.getFrom() + " - " + item.getTo();
    }
}
```

And assign it at ComboBox creation time:

```
ComboBox<MyObject> cb = new ComboBox<MyObject>(store, labelProvider);
```